# technique to iterate through the FirstName, LastName to create username

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am stuck on a situation where i am trying to generate password for a given username.

I am creating a username from the user's input through textbox for FirstName and LastName, by the user's lastname + first letter of the firstname. For e.x., If the user's First name is 'Ronald' and the last name is 'Test', i add the username in the database as 'Testr'. But if i had the same last name for another user and the firstname begins with the same name as existing user in the database, i add the first 2 letters of the firstname like this -

```
if (entities.Users.Any(a => a.LastName == tbLname.Text && a.FirstName.StartsWith(fname))) 
 username = (tbLname.Text + tbFname.Text.Substring(0,2)).ToLower();
```

Now the issue is, this works only if the first 2 letters match the first name. What if i had 3 or even 4 matching the first names?  I dont have a clue how to check for the remaining characters to have a unique username.

Any idea on how to achieve this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your rules if a user has the same first and last name as another user?  Your application would break if this happened.

Comment: You're probably going to have to rethink this a little bit. You won't be able to dynamically generate the user name based on first and last name every time, because you can never know how many matching names you may have. Perhaps generate a username the first time and then store it accordingly.

Comment: Why not just do a check to see if they are the same username, and then append an incremental number to it?  So, first one would be 'Testr', second would be 'Testr1', etc.

Comment: @JordanKaye  - You could iterate through every character of the first name until an open username is available, but, once you run out of characters the OP needs to provide more information as to what the requirements are.

Comment: @Ek0nomik agreed, I was getting at something like this.

Comment: @Ek0nomik, this app is just admin purpose to enter users and the only rule is to have a unique username based off the given first & last name.

Comment: @Kevin H, seems like a great idea to me...i tried this route, but the issue with this, is the counter increments.  i'm new to asp.net and i dont know how to cache the counters, if the admin, closes the app / page and starts again to reenter the users. my counter will start from 1 again...

Comment: @Ron - The problem is you can't guarantee a unique username based on first name and last name.  Two people can have the exact same name.  Maybe my name is also `Ronald Test`.  What do you want to happen in this scenario?

Comment: @Ek0nomik, you are correct, your solution provided perfect solution for my situation, now if i had 2 or 3 names with the same first name & last name, the username is unique by adding the next character from the first name, appended to the last name.

Comment: @Ron - What if you have 7 people named Ronald Test?  What would you do then?

Comment: @Ek0nomik, i just hit the break point for this :) - got an error for having this scenario - "Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length" - well, i did not get any specific requirements for this yet, if it matches all the first name and all the last name, so, i am good for now, but have to think about the solution for that in the mean time...

Comment: @Ek0nomik, one possible solution to provide the client, is to add numbers after the first match (Testr) and Testr1, Testr2, ...so on.

Comment: @Ron - Yeah, that would work fine.  I just wanted to make sure you knew that this code could cause a problem at some point until those requirements were determined.  Adding a number after the name would be very easy to implement.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is more information needed from the OP on this if the application wants to avoid bugs, but, in the meantime this should solve the question at hand.

```
//Store the first possible name.
var possibleUsername = string.Format("{0}{1}", tbLname.Text, tbFname.Text.Substring(0,1))

//Don't hit the database N times, instead get all the possible names in one shot.
var existingUsers = entities.Users.Where(u => u.Username.StartsWith(possibleUsername)).ToList();

//Find the first possible open username.
if (existingUsers.Count == 0) {
    //Create the user since the username is open.
} else {
    //Iterate through all the possible usernames and create it when a spot is open.
    for(var i = 1; i < existingUsers.Count; i++) {
        if (existingUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == string.Format("{0}{1}", tbLname.Text, tbFname.Text.Substring(0, i))) == null) {
            //Create the user since the user name is open.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome !! thanks Ek0nomik !! i was twisting my brain to arrive at a solution like this. just learning Linq, Asp.net...thanks for all your help.

Comment: Thank you for such a nice solution. But there is one little problem, it should be var existingUsers = entities.Users.Where(u => u.Username.StartsWith(possibleUsername)).ToList(); need one more ) before .ToList()

Comment: @piavgh - Good catch, it's been fixed.